# how can git identify repositories owner?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I wonder if someone can pretend as a real github repository owner and do some push in that repository.
Does github verify the repository owner by using user.name and user.email?

Comment: you need to authenticate yourself before pushing

Comment: how I authenticate myself? In my own repository I only enter user.name and user.email which I think so easy to be known by other peoples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you do the first `git clone` and then `git push` , you will see a screen like this:[image]

Depending if you use BitBucket or Github where you should enter your credentials.
Basically you login and you are good to go!
Good Luck with GIT and have fun Coding !

Answer (score 0):

Github will ask your username and password when you try to push for first time when using https and it will be cached on your computer until you change your credentials. Check this [reference](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/#platform-linux) about caching of github credentials